# How to update object record in an ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I want to update record in `ArrayList` in c#, I want to update my status to inactive of particular record of `ArrayList`,  here is the code below but this isn't working fine as it doesn't update status to inactive.

```
public Boolean changeAccStatus(int userid)
{
    Boolean result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) 
    {
        AccountDto dto = (AccountDto)list[i];
        if (dto.Userid == userid) {
            dto.Status = "Unactive";
            list[i] = dto;
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `ArrayList` rather than a strongly typed `List<T>`?

Comment: what differene it shall make.

Comment: BTW, it's 'inactive' rather than 'unactive'

Comment: @JunaidAkhtar: All the difference in the world. Work with generic collections for a while instead of the weakly typed collections... it makes life *so* much nicer (not to mention the availability of LINQ...)

Comment: ok thanks but tel me how to change status here ?

Answer (score 0):

if you can able to convert list to generic list than you can do this

```
 Func<int, AccountDto, bool> UpdateRecord= (y, x) => 
                  {
                    if( x.Userid== y){x.Status="Unactive";
                    return true; 
                  };
    List<AccountDto> mylist = new List<AccountDto>();
    var v = from x in mylist
            where UpdateRecord(userit-intvalue, x)
            select x;
```

also you can try this

```
List<AccountDto> mylist = new List<AccountDto>();

list.ForEach(x => {
    if( x.Userid== userid)
        x.Status="Unactive";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do  `(AccountDto)list[i].Status = "inactive";`

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

```
 foreach (var temp in list)
        {
            var t = temp as AccountDto;
            if (t != null && t.Userid.Trim().Equals(userid.Trim()))
                t.Status = "inactive";
        }
```

also think about doing re factoring to generic List< AccountDto> , this will give you the power of Linq directly